# Weird execution for subscribers of an event in C#

Tags: c#, events, user-controls, delegates, event-handling

I have an event and its method declared as follows, it's an authenticating event for a windows forms login control:

```
public event EventHandler<AuthenticateEventArgs> Authenticate;

protected void OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<AuthenticateEventArgs> handler = Authenticate;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }

    if (e.Authenticated)
    {
        OnLoggedIn(new EventArgs());
    }
        else
    {
        OnLoggedError(new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

The event is raised on a button click, now assume on some other project there are subscribers to this event as follows:

```
this.loginControl1.Authenticate += loginControl1_Authenticate;
this.loginControl1.Authenticate += delegate(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            ea.Authenticated = false;
        };
this.loginControl1.Authenticate += delegate(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            ea.Authenticated = true;
        };
this.loginControl1.Authenticate += delegate(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            ea.Authenticated = false;
        };
```

The `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);` is just a simulation for some process that takes some time. The problem is that the last subscriber performs the If condition in the `OnAuthenticate` method and raises the other event, the before subscribers does not. Code works perfectly for one subscriber. Where is the problem in this situation ?

Comment: What happens? Always `Authenticated` is false?

Comment: Yes. The Authenticated value will always be the value in the last subscriber whatever it is, true or false.

Comment: You want the `OnLoggedIn()` function to execute once and `OnLoggedError` to execute twice, with the given example?? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes that is what I want.

Comment: What would the parameters be for `OnLoggedIn()` and `OnLoggedError()`. Will you need the `AuthenticationArgs`?

Comment: These two events don't require a custom event args.

Comment: Declare `Authenticated` in `AuthenticateArgs` as a List<bool> instead of a `bool`. And in each handler `ea.Authenticated.Add(false)` or `ea.Authenticated.Add(true)`. Then after the execution is complete, iterate the list and call your functions accordingly. Just remember to have an empty list before calling your handlers.

Comment: seems logical, but do you have solution using threading, async, anything parallel ?

Comment: You want all your authentication methods to run in parallel?

Comment: Yes. Each one should raise either loggedIn or loggedError.

Comment: You would want to lookup `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`. Do you want me to help you with some code?

Comment: Yes please. I managed to call each subscriber alone using GetInvocationList and Delegate.Invoke.

Comment: `Invoke` is synchronous, `BeginInvoke` is async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted asynchronous execution of your authentication methods, you could work like this.

**Create a delegate that returns a `bool`**

`public delegate bool Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e);`

`Authenticate authHandler;`

You may or may not use the arguments but you can use or remove that later.

**Create your authentication methods**

```
bool AuthenticationMethod1(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //Simulate some long running task.
    return false; //Return true or false based on authentication failed or succeeded.
}

bool AuthenticationMethod2(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //Simulate some long running task.
    return true; //Return true or false based on authentication failed or succeeded.
}

bool AuthenticationMethod3(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //Simulate some long running task.
    return false; //Return true or false based on authentication failed or succeeded.
}
```

**Hook up the handlers**

```
authHandler += AuthenticationMethod1;
authHandler += AuthenticationMethod2;
authHandler += AuthenticationMethod3;
```

**Now execute**

```
if (authHandler != null)
{
    foreach (Authenticate handler in authHandler.GetInvocationList())
    {
        handler.BeginInvoke(this, e as AuthenticateEventArgs, new AsyncCallback(Callback), handler);
    }                
}
```

**LAST PART : Have you callback defined**

```
void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Authenticate d = (Authenticate)ar.AsyncState;
    if (d.EndInvoke(ar))
    {
       OnLoggedIn(new EventArgs());
    }
    else
    {
       OnLoggedError(new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try the code and see the result. Thanks for the assist :)

Comment: Perfect! that what I was looking for!

Comment: With your code I don't think i'll need a custom EventArgs class. I'll try that. Thanks for the assist man! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is well known behavior, Events execute in the order of subscription, so subscriber who suscribed last will overwrite all the previous values. You get to see the last subscriber's update (in this case false).

You can fix this by checking already authenticated and skip processing.

```
this.loginControl1.Authenticate += delegate(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
{
    if(ea.Authenticated)
    {
        return;
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ea.Authenticated = false;
};
this.loginControl1.Authenticate += delegate(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
{        
    if(ea.Authenticated)
    {
        return;
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ea.Authenticated = true;
};
this.loginControl1.Authenticate += delegate(object o, AuthenticateEventArgs ea)
{
    if(ea.Authenticated)
    {
        return;
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    ea.Authenticated = false;
};
```

Reason why because you see `Authenticated` false always is `handler(this, e);` will return only after invoking all subscribed methods. So your last subscriber sets `Authenticated` to false so you see false only when `if (e.Authenticated)` is executed.

Comment: The overwriting is no problem of me, but why the previous subscribers wouldn't evaluate the if and raise the other event? I want each subscriber to evaluate the if and raise other event based on it. It might not seems logical for this code, but it's just a special case searching i'm searching in it.

Comment: You mean you expect `OnLoggedIn` to fire right? Please try this, this will solve your problem for sure

Answer (score 0):

remove event by this code:

```
this.loginControl1.Authenticate -= loginControl1_Authenticate;
```

Comment: It didn't solve it. Still the last subscriber only evaluates the if and raise other event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all the event subscribers will executes on same thread as the function who triggered them so when the execution reaches

```
        handler(this, e);
```

the execution will move to the first subscriber code

```
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ea.Authenticated = false;
```

and then the execution goes to the second subscriber. At the end it will execute the last subscriber code and then the execution backs to the caller function

```
protected void OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e)
```

and the execution continue from the event trigger line to the second if statement and at that point the value of ea.Authenticated is false as last subscriber set it.

if you want to raise each event on a different threads check [Trigger events on separated threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881808/raising-events-on-separate-thread)